# api call in Angular 8 , result is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http, angular-http-interceptors

I have a angular 8 application and want to call a Get api call.

But I get this error:

```
stack: "ReferenceError: result is not defined↵    at eval (eval at push../src/app/dossier/dossier-physical/dossier-physical.component.ts.DossierPhysicalComponent.ngOnInit
```

This is the ts file:

```
export class DossierPhysicalComponent implements OnInit {
  entries: Array<DossierEntry> = [];
  single: DossierEntry;
  showSingle: boolean;
  dossiersLoaded = false;

  constructor(
    private healthAPIService: HealthAPIService,
    private documentCorrespondencService: DocumentCorrespondenceService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.healthAPIService.getDossierEntry('physical').subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result.values);
      this.entries = result;
      this.dossiersLoaded = true;
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the service:

```
 getDossierEntry( type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
    const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
    return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
  }
```

And this is the total error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical", ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

So what I do wrong here?

Thank you

The problem Is that I try to refactoring the Get method. Because I have a service: health.api.service.

and there are customised api calls. Like this:

```
 get( route: string, responseType: RespType = 'json', fullResponse: boolean = false, params = null): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke( 'GET', route, null, responseType, fullResponse, true, params);
  }
```

and the invoke method looks like this:

```
 invoke(
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE',
    route: string,
    body?: any,
    responseType: RespType = 'json', // PDF gets translated to array buffer and the application/pdf accept header
    fullResponse: boolean  = false,
    needsAuthenticatedUser = true,
    params: HttpParams = null
  ): Observable<any> {
    const user$ = this.authService.loginStatus()
                      .pipe( take( 1 ) );

    return user$.pipe(
      map( user => {
        let parsedRoute = route;
        if ( needsAuthenticatedUser ) {
          if ( !user ) {
            throw Error( 'Tried to call api that requires login without a user profile present' );
          } else {
            parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{userId}', user.profile.sub);
            parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{patientUUID}', user.profile.participant);
          }
        }
        return environment.ApiOrigin + parsedRoute;
      } ),
      switchMap( url => {
        const accessToken = this.authService.getAccessToken();

        const headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept'      : HealthAPIService._responseTypes[ responseType ].mime
        };

        if ( !!accessToken ) {
          headers[ 'Authorization' ] = `Bearer  ${accessToken}`;
        }

        const options = {
          body        : body,
          responseType: HealthAPIService._responseTypes[ responseType ].decode as
            | 'json'
            | 'text'
            | 'arraybuffer',
          headers     : new HttpHeaders( headers )
        };
        if ( fullResponse ) {
          options[ 'observe' ] = 'response';
        }
        if (params !== null) {
          options['params'] = params;
        }

        return this.http.request( method, url, options )
                   .pipe( catchError(err => this.handleError(err)) );
      } )
    );
  }
```

But I want to get rid of that customised Get method. And just want to call it with the HttpClient module of Angular.

This is the error handling:

```
private handleError( error: any ): Observable<any> {
    if ( error.status && error.status === 401 ) {
      console.error( 'Authorization failed, trying to login.' );
      this.authService.requestLogin();
    }
    console.dir( error );
    if ('error' in error) {
      // This is necessary to allow measurement-form-component
      // handleFormErrors to give correct feedback.
      return observableThrowError(error);
    }
    return observableThrowError( error.message || error );
  }
```

when I try thtat. I stiil get this error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical", ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
constructor: ƒ HttpErrorResponse(init)
__proto__: Object
```

So I have it now like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.healthAPIService.getDossierEntry('physical').subscribe((result: any)=> {
       console.log(result.values);
       this.entries = result;
       this.dossiersLoaded = true;
   });
 }
```

and this:

```
  getDossierEntry( type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
    const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
    return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
  }
```

then I will get this error:

```
core.js:7376 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical", ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

```
stack: "ReferenceError: result is not defined↵    at eval (eval at push../src/app/dossier/dossier-physical/dossier-physical.component.ts.DossierPhysicalComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:4200/dossier-dossier-module-ngfactory.js:18184:14), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at DossierPhysicalComponent.push../src/app/dossier/dossier-physical/dossier-physical.component.ts.DossierPhysicalComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:4200/dossier-dossier-module-ngfactory.js:18184:14)↵    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:37850:19)↵    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46063:20)↵    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46025:16)↵    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46659:38)↵    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46619:13)↵    at Object.updateDirectives (http://localhost:4200/dossier-dossier-module-ngfactory.js:18152:711)↵    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46611:21)↵    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:46007:14)"
```

and this is the HttpMaintenanceInterceptor:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class HttpMaintenanceInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService ) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getAccessToken()}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

I have it now like this:

```
getDossierEntry( patientUUID: string, type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;

  console.log(this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/' + patientUUID + '/DossierEntry/' + entryType));

  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType);
}
```

and this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.documentCorrespondencService.getDossierEntry('physical').subscribe((result: any)=> {
       console.log(result.values);
       this.entries = result;
       this.dossiersLoaded = true;
   });
 }
```

I get this output:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator
project: ƒ (res)
thisArg: undefined
__proto__: Object
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object
```

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/$%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/all", ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /api/patient/$%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/all</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/patient/$%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/all: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/$%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/all"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

even if I do this:

```
getDossierEntry( patientUUID: string, type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  patientUUID = '0d584905-fc20-4723-870a-0f0214419507';
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;

  console.log(this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/' + patientUUID + '/DossierEntry/' + entryType ));

  console.log(patientUUID);
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/' + patientUUID + '/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
}
```

doenst work

Comment: You're calling a URL that returns a 404 error. Probably your handling of the patientUUID in the URL is incorrect.

Comment: You seem not replacing `patientUUID` value when making the api call.

Comment: But why would the subscriber _get_ that undefined, if it's an error? `throwError("you won't see this message").subscribe(console.log)` prints nothing. Is there an interceptor somewhere in the middle, eating HTTP error responses and emitting empty values?

Comment: Update post ok, will be nice

Comment: see post update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of updating API url with `patientUUID`

**Option 1:**

```
 getDossierEntry( patientUUID: string, type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
    const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
    return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/' + patientUUID + '/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
  }
```

**Option 2:** Other way of using `patientUUID` in URL

```
getDossierEntry( patientUUID: string, type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
        const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
        return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType);
  }
```

**Issue** : `patientUUID` value is not getting appended to URL at intended location and getting 404 not found as it turns out to be invalid

To fix this issue update API url as above with parameters - **patientUUID** and **type** and to debug add console before return to check the url as below

```
console.log(this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/' + patientUUID + '/DossierEntry/' + entryType)
```

Comment: Thank you . I will check it tomorrow and wil let you now.

Comment: But can I sent you the files?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton, i dont think SO allows sending files, but you can create stackblitz to replicate your issue

Comment: But we can go to chat. But can you invite me for chat? Because I dont see the function here.

Comment: Naga, are you there? I am testing it now

Comment: But can we go to chat.

Comment: I am using mobile and not at my computer right now,  Please test and let me know if face any issue/error

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: But it has nothing to do with the interceptor. in my post

Comment: Can you try first option once ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that one. But it doesnt take the patientUUID. Because even when I do a hardcoded patientUUID than it also doesnt work.

Comment: and if I do this:   console.log(patientUUID); it returns physical.

Comment: use '/api/patient/' + patientUUID + '/DossierEntry/' + entryType  , from post , I see you are using ${patientUUID}

Comment: I am in CST timezone

Comment: I am using that: return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/' + patientUUID + '/DossierEntry/' + entryType );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199865/discussion-between-mightycode-newton-and-naga-sai-a).

Comment: I am in the chat now. But I think it has to do with the invoke method. But I dont know how to change that.

Comment: Oke, problem solved. Thank you for your effort! oke, nice

Answer (score 0):

As i see the response you are getting is 404, which means the URL is not found.

In your code,

you are not substituting the value of **`patientUUID`** that you can check in the URL

```
return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType
```

Comment: But what I have to change then?

Comment: Can you say What I do wrong? OR that I have to post more code? Would be nice

Comment: Hi I added the Interceptor. But what I have to change  then? Thank you

Comment: But so How to emite the patientUUID  then in the URL? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in developer mode you should add proxy.conf.json to forward to your server:
for example:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1337",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand this. what is 1337?? I updated the post

Comment: it is just an example. my server is listening to on port 1337. If you call relative url(/api) you should redirect it to your server, if you call external with ip, you should set absolute url, since the relative calls back to server which runs angular.

Comment: Oke, but this is not the problem. I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Map result type to any or

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.healthAPIService.getDossierEntry('physical').subscribe((result:DossierEntry[])=> {
      console.log(result.values);
      this.entries = result;
      this.dossiersLoaded = true;
    });
  }
```

**OR**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.healthAPIService.getDossierEntry('physical').subscribe((result:any)=> {
       console.log(result.values);
       this.entries = result;
       this.dossiersLoaded = true;
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. But still get an error. Updated the post

Comment: could you please put result inside the parenthesis like ** `(result:any)=>`** and check once.

Comment: But has it nothing to do with the invoke method? Because I dont trigger that method ofcourse , when I am using the httpClient

Comment: atSantosh DO you have other suggestions?

Comment: I added the INterceptor

Comment: Please check your backend URL. You are hitting wrong one `http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical`. It should be `http://localhost:1337/api/patient/<patientUUID>/DossierEntry/type/physical`. and <patientUUID> should be replace with actual ID like if patientUUID is 11001 then url should be `http://localhost:1337/api/patient/11001/DossierEntry/type/physical`

Comment: Yes, understand. But that is the problem. So why it cant find the user id? the correct url from Swagger is this: /api/patient/{participantId}/DossierEntry/type/{dossierEntryCategoryType}

Comment: What I have to change about the api call then? getDossierEntry( type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  console.log('hello');
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType )
}

Comment: So even when I do hardcoded patientUUID, like this:  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/{0d584905-fc20-4723-870a-0f0214419507}/DossierEntry/' + entryType );